# C++/CLR Login form - Opening form on button press

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, clr

I am new to C++ and I am doing a exercise where I make a login form. I am struggling with opening my other form on button press, can anyone help/guide me. Thanks

```
private: System::Void btnLogin_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    if (txtUsername->Text == "admin")
    {
        if (txtPassword->Text == "admin")
        {
            Form^ Account = gcnew Form();
            Account.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Incorrect Password, Please try again.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Incorrect Username, Please try again.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a click handler for the button you want to open the other form with, by double clicking the button. In that function that is created, open your other form.

```
button1_OnClick(..)
{
    Form2^ second = gcnew Form2();
    second->Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I don't fully understand the code, I understand that 'Form2' will be the second form I have created but what does the 'second' mean?

Comment: I have added my code above, my original form is called 'LoginPage' and the form I would like to open is called 'Accounts'

Comment: Sorry, since it is C++ CLI you will need to dereference the object before using a method (use -> instead of .). I have updated my answer.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, it seems that there isn't much information out there about this, really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! C++ CLI is pretty niche nowadays, but it is great for using older unmanaged (native C++) code with more modern GUI tools like Windows Forms.